# What happens to the 2s orbital in carbon-hydrogen bonds?

Tags: bond, electronic-configuration, hydrocarbons

I was taught in high school that carbon atoms by themselves are capable of establishing covalent bonds with with as far as four hydrogens atoms.

[image]

Nowadays, trying to understand the topic in-depth, I am confused about orbitals regarding this case. As far as I know, in the carbon atom's outer shell, the 2s orbital is filled, and the 2p orbital has two lonely electrons, but at the same time, each hydrogen forms a bond with one of this outer shell electrons. Does this mean the 2s orbital splits, or is there any other explanation?